# How to make checkbox checked?

Tags: symfony

I have this field in form builder

```
->add('pay_method', 'choice', array(
            'choices' => array(
                'telnet' => 'Image',
            ),
            'expanded' => true,
            'label' => 'Способ оплаты',
        ))
```

with ony one option yet, but how can i make this checked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i did it through JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Add `attr` index with `'checked' => 'checked'`:

```
->add('pay_method', 'choice', array(
        'choices' => array(
            'telnet' => 'Image',
        ),
        'expanded' => true,
        'label' => 'Способ оплаты',
        'attr' => array('checked' => 'checked')
    ))
```

Comment: now i have <div id="cabletv_pay_form_pay_method" checked="checked">. Still not work.

Answer (score 0):

Set it on the object or array the form is used for.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default value by either setting it in your domain model:

```
private $pay_method = 'telnet';
```

or

```
$object->pay_method = 'telnet'
```

or by specifying the "data" option of the field:

```
$builder->add('pay_method', 'choice', array(
    'choices' => array(
        'telnet' => 'Image',
        ...
    ),
    'data' => 'telnet',
    'expanded' => true,
    'label' => ...,
));
```

Comment: No, i need for set of radiobuttons, but choose the "default" value

Comment: Ok. Your question was confusing, because it contained only one possible choice. I updated my answer now.